# UITableView inside UIScrollView does not trigger ScrollToRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I created a UITableView and added it into UIScrollView container. 
At the top of the page I have a map displayed and I want to trigger the ScrollToRow behavior each time the user clicks on a marker from the map.
The method that calls this is:

```
 private void OnMarkerClick(MapView mapView, Marker marker)
        {
            var markerLocation = marker.Title;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(markerLocation))
            {
                var index = ViewModel.Items.IndexOf(ViewModel.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected));
                var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(index, 0);
                DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.High).DispatchAsync(() =>
                {
                    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
                    {
                        _tableView.ReloadData();
                        _tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, true);
                        _tableView.LayoutIfNeeded();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

The index of the selected item is got correctly, only the scrolling behavior is not working. 
Any idea why this is not happening?

Comment: I think you don't need `reloadData and layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: Don't put tableview inside a scrollView and remove the reloadData and layoutIfNeeded.